# Julia Dataframe - parallel join DataFrame operations?

Tags: dataframe, asynchronous, join, julia

I am wondering if there is a way to parallelize leftjoin operations in Julia

For example, I have the following DataFrames :

df1:

```
 Id   LDC   LDR
  a  ldc1  ldr1
  b  ldc2  ldr2
  c  ldc3  ldr4
  d  ldc2  ldr3
```

df2 :

```
  LDC  dc1  dc2  dc3
  ldc1  0.5  0.4  0.2
  ldc2  0.1  0.6  0.7
  ldc3  0.4  0.9  0.3
```

df3

```
   LDR  lap1  lap2  lap3
  ldr1  0.05  0.06  0.07
  ldr2  0.10  0.12  0.13
  ldr3  0.01  0.01  0.02
  ldr4  0.05  0.06  0.07
```

I currently make a serial join operation as below

df1 = leftjoin(df1, df2, on = "LDC")

df1 = leftjoin(df1, df3, on = "LDR")

which give me the desired result :

```
 Id   LDC   LDR  dc1  dc2  dc3  lap1  lap2  lap3
  a  ldc1  ldr1  0.5  0.4  0.2  0.05  0.06  0.07
  b  ldc2  ldr2  0.1  0.6  0.7  0.10  0.12  0.13
  d  ldc2  ldr3  0.1  0.6  0.7  0.01  0.01  0.02
  c  ldc3  ldr4  0.4  0.9  0.3  0.05  0.06  0.07
```

My question is : Is there a way to "populate" the initial DF (df1) with a parallelized join operation to obtain the same result ?

Thanks for any help you could provide

UPDATE : Here is the code to generate df1,df2 & df3.

```
df1 = DataFrame(Id = ["a","b","c","d"],
                LDC = ["ldc1","ldc2","ldc3","ldc2"],
                LDR = ["ldr1","ldr2","ldr4","ldr3"]
                )
df2 = DataFrame(LDC = ["ldc1","ldc2","ldc3"],
                dc1 = [0.5,0.4,0.2],
                dc2 = [0.1,0.6,0.7],
                dc3 = [0.4,0.9,0.3]
                )
df3 = DataFrame(LDR = ["ldr1","ldr2","ldr3"],
                lap1 = [0.05,0.06,0.07],
                lap2 = [0.10,0.12,0.13],
                lap3 = [0.01,0.01,0.02],
                lap4 = [0.05,0.06,0.07]
                )
```

Comment: `@async` is used for green threads - there is no speedup in any scenario unless I/O is involved. You need to use either `Threads.@threads` or `Distributed.@distributed`. Since you have not provided a MWE it is hard to give a relevant example. Perhaps see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and try to update your post to make it useful for the others.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will clarify my post with a relevant example.

Comment: @Przemyslaw Szufel,  I edited my question as you mentioned. Hope it will help.

Comment: Could you please provide the code to generate `df1`, `df2`, `df3`. Generally you could create threads that would create `df1_1` and `df1_2` and then, assuming they have the same number of rows just combine them to a larger dataframe.

Comment: I added the code to generate the dataframes. Thanks for you help.